# Recorrer tr y obtener los data-efectivo de cada tr

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo un `tr` con el atributo `data-efectivo` que contiene un número decimal variable (ejem: 9.20). Lo que deseo es recorrer todos los `tr` de mi tabla y obtener *la suma matemática* de estos atributos.

Mi tabla:

```html
<table id="tbfinanzas-delivery">
    <tbody>
        <tr data-efectivo="10.6"><td>hola</td></tr>
        <tr data-efectivo=""><td>hola</td></tr>
        <tr data-efectivo="95"><td>hola</td></tr>
        <tr data-efectivo="100.00"><td>hola</td></tr>
        <tr data-efectivo=""><td>hola</td></tr>
        <tr data-efectivo="10.6"><td>hola</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Mi código jQuery:

```javascript
function obtenerSuma(){
    $("#tbfinanzas-delivery tbody tr").find("[data-efectivo]").each(function () {
        alert(this).attr("data-efectivo");
    });
}
```

> **Nota:** Yo uso jQuery, pero si la solución se da en JavaScript no hay problema.

Answer (score 0):

```
let $table = document.getElementById("tbfinanzas-delivery"),
    $tr = $table.querySelectorAll("tr"),
    sumatoria = 0;

$tr.forEach(el => {
    let valor = el.getAttribute("data-efectivo");
    valor = valor > 0? valor : 0
    sumatoria += parseFloat(valor);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Partiendo de la siguiente cita:

> Tengo un `tr` con el atributo `data-efectivo` que contiene un número decimal variable (ejem: 9.20). Lo que deseo es recorrer todos los `tr` de mi tabla y obtener la suma matemática de estos atributos.

### Lo puedes recorrer de cualquiera de las dos (02) formas

#### Recorrido con jQuery

Puede utilizar la siguiente sintaxis para jQuery:

```js
const obtenerSuma = () => {
  let suma = 0;

  $("[data-efectivo]").each(function(key, element) {
    const value = $(element).data("efectivo");
    suma += isNaN(value) ? 0 : Number(value);
  });

  console.log("Total =>", suma);
};

obtenerSuma();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="tbfinanzas-delivery">
  <tbody>
    <tr data-efectivo="10.6"><td>hola</td></tr>
    <tr data-efectivo=""><td>hola</td></tr>
    <tr data-efectivo="95"><td>hola</td></tr>
    <tr data-efectivo="100.00"><td>hola</td></tr>
    <tr data-efectivo=""><td>hola</td></tr>
    <tr data-efectivo="10.6"><td>hola</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Es decir, se seleccionan todas las filas que contengan el atributo `data-efectivo` mediante el selector de atributo `"[data-efectivo]"`, es decir:

```javascript
$("[data-efectivo]").each(function (key, element) {
    ...
});
```

Recorremos los elementos que contienen los atributos antes mencionado mediante el método `.each` y le pasamos como argumento, una función, tal y como se observó en el ejemplo anterior.

Luego, obtienes el valor del atributo `data-efectivo` mediante el método `data` de jQuery:

```javascript
const value = $(element).data(element);
```

Y posteriormente sumamos el valor obtenido en cada iteración:

```javascript
suma += isNaN(value) ? 0 : Number(value);
```

Tome en cuenta, que en el ejemplo anterior se utilizó un operador ternario, es decir:

```javascript
condicion ? verdadero : falso;
```

Por lo tanto, si `value` no es un número (**`NaN`**) asignará 0, de lo contrario, tomará el valor numérico en forma de cadena y la convertirá a número mediante la función `Number`.

#### Recorrido con JavaScript

También puede hacerlo con JavaScript. El paso es similar al anterior, por ejemplo:

```js
const obtenerSuma = () => {
  let suma = 0;

  document.querySelectorAll("[data-efectivo]").forEach(function(element) {
    const value = element.dataset.efectivo;
    suma += isNaN(value) ? 0 : Number(value);
  });

  console.log("Total =>", suma);
};

obtenerSuma();
```

```html
<table id="tbfinanzas-delivery">
  <tbody>
    <tr data-efectivo="10.6"><td>hola</td></tr>
    <tr data-efectivo=""><td>hola</td></tr>
    <tr data-efectivo="95"><td>hola</td></tr>
    <tr data-efectivo="100.00"><td>hola</td></tr>
    <tr data-efectivo=""><td>hola</td></tr>
    <tr data-efectivo="10.6"><td>hola</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Para el caso anterior, lo único que cambió fue:

```javascript
$("[data-efectivo]").each(function (key, element) {
    ...
});
```

Por esta otra:

```javascript
document.querySelectorAll("[data-efectivo]").each(function (element) {
    ...
});
```

Además de esta:

```javascript
const value = $(element).data("efectivo");
```

Por esta otra:

```javascript
const value = element.dataset.efectivo;
```